# How can I use the data from Google Analytics dashboard in my site?

Tags: codeigniter, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics, and I have created a custom dashboard. I want get this dashboard's graphs or data so that I can show it on my site.

I have tried some code to display the total page count, but don't know how to get the dashboard data. Is this possible? Any idea how to do this?

My code is as follows:

```
$db_data = array();
define('ga_profile_id',$ga_profile_id);
$ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);
$dimensions = array('pagePath');
$metrics = array('uniquePageviews');
$sort = '-uniquePageviews';

$fromDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
$toDate = date('Y-m-d');

$mostPopular = $ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,$dimensions, $metrics, $sort, null, $fromDate, $toDate, 1, 10);
$i = 0;
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
    $db_data['landing_page'][$i]['page_views'] = $result->getUniquePageviews();
    $db_data['landing_page'][$i]['path'] = $result->getPagePath();
    $i++;
}

$sort ="";
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
$toDate = date('Y-m-d');
$mostPopular1 = $ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('browser','mobileDeviceModel'),array('pageviews','visits'), $sort, null, $fromDate, $toDate, 1, 10);
$db_data['mobile_users'] = $ga->getVisits();

$data['content']=$this->load->view('client/analytics_report',$db_data,true);
$data['active_menu']='clients';
$data['page_title']='Client Listings';
```

Comment: If you don't want to mess with the API, check out [embeddedanalytics.com](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  This is precisely why we exist.